# Visual Studio LightSwitch - How can I change the text color of a DataGrid Column

Tags: .net, visual-studio-lightswitch

Example : A Visual Studio LightSwitch Screen showing 2 Columns Name & Salary in DataGrid

All I want is the text of Salary Column to be font-bold and red in color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this thread. Not only can you colour the text you can colour the columns and or rows also.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/e901f2c7-a416-46ff-8144-c7b6ab3af31d

Otis

Answer (score 2):

You must be doing this in LS V1. It's quite difficult to acheieve what you want in V1. It can be done though, see this article: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Custom-Datagrid-coloring-d9b7c7bd

There are "formatting" improvements in V2 (VS 2012 & LS V2 are currently at Release Candicate stage) that will probably allow you to do what you want without resorting to code (as this has been a frequest request).

Comment: The link from MS shows me to write Custom DataGrid feels like almost reinventing the wheel. So I understand their is nothing in LS V1 that will do it